# Navigation borders not the same height

Tags: html, css, layout

I am working on this site: http://www.problemio.com and I have very little clue about css :) and somehow chugging along with the help of StackOverflow.

I am stumped once again as to why the little vertical line borders in the navigation bars are different height?

I would ideally like to make them slightly shorter than the font size. Is there a way for me to do that?

Thanks!

Here is my css:

```
.menusystem 
{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
}

.menusystem ul, .menusystem li 
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menusystem li 
{
    list-style: none outside none;
}

.menusystem ul 
{
    list-style: none;
}

.menusystem ul li ul 
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.6em;
    right: 0;
}

.menusystem li a 
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menusystem ul li.main_menu_li 
{
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 7px;

    display: block;
    float:right;

    margin-right:0.2em;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: solid 1px white;   
    line-height: 1em;   
}

.menusystem ul li.main_menu_li_left
{
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 7px;   

    display: block;
    float:right;
    margin-right:0.2em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1em;   
}

/* IE-Win (Holly hack) reads the list item line breaks, so lets hide those \*/
* html ul li { float: left; }
* html ul li a { height: 1%; }


.menusystem li:hover ul, .menusystem li.mouseHover ul { 
    display: block;
}

.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li a
{
    color: #fff;


    font-size: 80%;
    text-shadow: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2e6ea4;
    border-top: 0px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2E6EA4;
}


.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li.first a
{
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 14px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 14px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #2e6ea4;
}


.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li.last a
{
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 14px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 14px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 14px;
}


.menusystem li ul.child_menu_ul li a:hover 
{
    color: #ff0;
    background: #2e6ea4; 
}

/*.menusystem li.main_menu_li a */
.menusystem ul.child_menu_ul a
{
    color: #fff;            
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

.menusystem li.main_menu_li a:hover 
{
    color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different heights because they are borders, and the elements have different heights.

Give them a uniform height:

```
.menusystem ul li.main_menu_li {
  height: 27px;
}
```

Comment: you mean the elements have different set heights? where? I am not noticing.  Or they are diff heights cause one is a form?

Comment: also removing the padding-top rule and replacing it with an appropriate margin-top rule will help align it correctly.

Comment: If you use Firebug for Firefox or Chrome's Inspector, just inspect the elements. All three have different heights.

Comment: @blender they all have height set to line-height: 1em; - is that not going to work?

Comment: @Joseph what is wrong with doing the padding-top?  How would you make the margin-top? Same thing as current except swap margin for padding?

Comment: `line-height` sets the height of each line of text, not of the element itself.

Comment: @GeekedOut: your site's menu is a bit hacky and won't work in the long run. You need to sit down for a while and design it well. Look at some examples, see how other websites do it.

Comment: @GeekedOut that's correct.  the major difference here is that padding will extend the border height while margin will not. see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/TsdWW/

Comment: Btw, did you guys add a problem for "this site rules?" or was it someone else? :)